# Why use .factory in AngularJS instead of declaring as a variable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, factory, angularfire

Currently learning Javascript and Angular JS. I'm trying to see if I can get around not using .factory by just declaring what it returns as a variable and then referencing it.

Why must I use factory instead of just declaring what it returns as a a function? Is there anyway to get around it.

JAVASCRIPT CODE 1 (MY CODE): http://jsfiddle.net/chrisguzman/s4dBE/4/

```
  myapp.controller("SampleController",
    function SampleController($scope,$firebase){
        var ref = new Firebase("https://helloworldtest.firebaseio.com/text");
        var service = $firebase(ref);
        service.$bind($scope, "text");
    })
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE 2 (ORIGINAL CODE): http://jsfiddle.net/chrisguzman/s4dBE/3/

```
angular.module("sampleApp", ["firebase"])
  .factory("sampleService", ["$firebase", function($firebase) {
    var ref = new Firebase("https://helloworldtest.firebaseio.com/text");
    return $firebase(ref);
  }])
  .controller("SampleController", ["$scope", "sampleService",
    function($scope, service) {
      service.$bind($scope, "text");
    }
  ]);
```

Bonus question: Is there any other way to write the second script of code differently. The reason I ask is because it would help in understanding it further. In particular, I'd like to see the same task be accomplished without the use of factory, and it would be awesome see a function as the second argument of the controller (as that's what've been exposed to).

Comment: Most people have the opposite problem...how to get data out of controller to use elsewhere. Your app is obviously not very complex or you would appreciate leaving it in factory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of the factory is to have a single source point for your data and you can inject that factory in other controllers.  You would have to duplicate Firebase in each controller you wanted to use it as opposed to just injecting the factory. For a simple one controller application, this isn't really any issue, but as your application grows, it would become a big issue.

One sample of using a factory:

```
var app = angular.module('firebaseApp',['firebase']);

app.factory('FBService',function($firebase) {
    var firebase_url = "https://helloworldtest.firebaseio.com/";

    return {
        ref: function(ref_path) {
            var new_ref = new Firebase(firebase_url + '/' + ref_path + '/');
            return $firebase(new_ref);
        }
    }
});

app.controller('List1Ctrl',function($scope,FBService) {
    $scope.list1 = FBService.ref('list1');
});

app.controller('List2Ctrl',function($scope,FBService) {
    $scope.list2 = FBService.ref('list2');
});
```

Comment: Aren't factories singletons? So regardless of the times it is injected it should just resolve to the single instance. Right?

Comment: @David, yes, services are singletons, however, you can modify their variables as the edited answer above illustrates.

Also, this might help if you need more information:
http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/08/understanding-service-types/

Comment: Ahh I see. My confusion comes from the fact that I place the new Firebase instance as a private field in my factories. I then use a thin API to grab back the data from them. A less flexible approach, but provides reuse of the Firebase instance.

Comment: Yeah, there are probably better ways to handle this, but this is just one example of a reusable service.

Comment: As long as you're not slamming everything on $scope, that makes me happy.

Comment: Slamming everything on $scope?  Not sure I understand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57710/discussion-between-david-and-rob).